# PHPExcel always printing weird Script on exported file

Tags: php, phpexcel, codeigniter-4

I'm working on a project where I use Codeigniter 4 and PHPexcel library. One of feature is exporting data to excel and csv from MySql database. Here is my controller:

```
namespace App\Controllers;

use App\Models\transaksiModel;
use PHPExcel;
use PHPExcel_IOFactory;

class Transaksi extends BaseController
{
public function export()
    {
        $listData = new transaksiModel();
        $listData = $listData->getData();

        $objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();
        $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
        // set Header
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('A1', 'First Name');
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('B1', 'Last Name');
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('C1', 'Email');
        // set Row
        $rowCount = 2;
        foreach ($listData as $list) {
            $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('A' . $rowCount, $list->fname);
            $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('B' . $rowCount, $list->lname);
            $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('C' . $rowCount, $list->email);
            $rowCount++;
        }

        $filename = "personlist" . date("Y-m-d-H-i-s") . ".csv";
        header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="' . $filename . '"');
        header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');
        $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'CSV');
        $objWriter->save($filename);
    } 
}
```

The code is working fine but it keep printing weird script on output file, after the data rows as shown below.
[image]
How can i get rid of that script?
Any suggestion would be big help. Thank you

Comment: You shouldn't really be using phpexcel anymore if you can. It was abandoned and archived 4 years ago. I'd recommand taking a look at https://laravel-excel.com/ instead - It's built on top of phpspreadsheet (successor to phpexcel) and adds a nice userfriendly interface for import/export of data through Laravel.

Comment: I have no idea how I read "Codeigniter 4" and turned that into "Laravel" in my head. My point above regarding phpexcel still stands. It should still be avoided if you can, and replaced by phpspreadsheet instead.

Comment: thanks for suggestion, i'll consider that

Comment: This looks like you are getting parts of your template appended to the output, after the excel data. You could try and simply `exit;` at the end of your method there, but I am guessing there is probably a dedicated method in CI as well, to make an action not use any of the default templating.

Comment: Thank you @CBroe it's finally dissapear from my output file

Comment: Use [PhpSpreadsheet](https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) the real successor of PHPexcel